# Unexpected behaviour when writing modifications by ASTNode.copySubtrees() to file

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am writing some Builder pattern insertion code and part of that involves copying fields from the top-level class to an autogenerated, nested Builder class. To do so, I call `ASTNode.copySubtrees()` to replicate those top-level class fields and then remove any `final` modifiers from the (supposedly deep!) copies. However, when writing changes back to source code file via `CompilationUnit.rewrite()` and `TextEdit.apply()`, I discovered that the final modifiers are not removed in the source code.

Playing around with it some more, I further discovered that the changes are made correctly in AST - just not correctly translated into changes of the source code: passing the top-level class declaration to `System.out.println()` right before `rewrite()` reveals that the `final` modifiers have been removed in memory correctly; still, they do not get removed from the source code.

The workaround that I am currently using is to copy the field subtrees to a temporary AST and from there to the nested Builder class, which works like a charm.

Am I missing something here or can someone confirm or deny if this is a (known?) bug in the JDT/Eclipse?

Comment: There are "Save Actions" that can modify the code to add `final` - Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions. Maybe you have those turned on?

Comment: No, they're turned off. It's not just restricted to `final` either. What makes me think this might be a bug is that copying to a fresh AST first and then copying back to the original AST works, just not directly copying within the same one.

Comment: You could try searching or reporting on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=advanced). If you decide to report a bug they will want a [mre]

Comment: Sounds like a concurrency issue on your side, not like an Eclipse bug. Look into Eclipse code how those methods are used. Please show a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I am using a single thread. However, I can see on Bugzilla that the unexpected behaviour has been reported before here: [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319448). The attached file by Keith Power over there demonstrates my issue pretty well. I could add to that only that the bug still persists, that the intermediary AST is manipulated correctly but written incorrectly to source and that copying to a fresh AST seems like a functional workaround for the time being.

Comment: Please read the [documentation how to manipulating Java code](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_manip.htm). There are also hints in the Javadoc of `CompilationUnit.rewrite()`. IMHO there is no unexpected behavior, but some complexity because of performance (which the bug reporter also seemed to missed).

Comment: You're alluding to copying operations not being recorded, I take it? I am just reading that in the javadoc to `CompilationUnit.recordModifications()` right above `rewrite()` at least. Well, the behaviour is sort of unexpected in the sense that `ASTNode.copySubtree()` promises a deep copy but does not mention explicitly that inserting the copied nodes back into AST will not result in properly recorded modifications. I think it's relevant information. Anyway, I have a workaround that works for now, but thanks for illuminating the issue, it's appreciated.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the AST and the serialized editor content (sequence of characters) are two data structures, and _copySubtree_ only changes the AST without updating the editor content for performance reasons.